# How to fix blinking issue in WebView (SDK 8) on scroll

Tags: android, webview, scrollview, blink

In my app I am using WebView to show the HTML content. My WebView is in ScrollView. It is blink on scrolling the screen. Now, I know there is method to overcome this but it works on SDK > 11

```
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
```

When I am using this in my App. App gets force closed since I am using SDK 8. Is there any way to fix this. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding android:hardwareAccelerated="false" to the activity in menifest file worked for me :)